# Prove that $MA \neq A^T M$, where M is positive definite, and A doesn’t have distinct roots

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

\Prove or refute the following statement

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ be a matrix  such that $MA \neq A^TM$ for
> all positive definite matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$, then the
> characteristic polynomial for $A$ must have a complex (non-real) root or
> a root with algebraic multiplicity greater than 1.

I’ve attempted this question from a mock paper for hours and I just can’t get anywhere. I’ve tried using JNF, by contradiction assuming A is diagonizable but I’ve got nowhere and would like a little push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Suppose the contrary. Then $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$. In this case, can you construct a positive definite matrix $M$ such that $MA$ is real symmetric?

A further hint:

> Let $A=PDP^{-1}$ be a diagonalisation over $\mathbb R$. To make $MA=(MP)DP^{-1}$ a symmetric matrix, can you relate $MP$ to $P^{-1}$?

Comment: Hey thanks, after making M the symmetric matrix P^-TSP^-1 and believe I proved the statement

Comment: This question is somewhat related to my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42072/does-knowing-a-conjugation-of-a-to-at-determine-eigenvalues-of-a. An example $A$  that I had in mind there was not diagonalizable over $R$ and $M$ was symmetric but not positive definite. The comments were interesting.